# Paid Membership Pro if statement in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the [www.paidmembershipspro.com](http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/) plugin on my wordpress site and I want to do an if statement in my wordpress theme...

```
if (has membership) {
    // echo
} else {

}
```

I've gone through the docs and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [their docs](http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/require-membership-function/) (you need to sign up to view them) you can use `pmpro_hasMembershipLevel` to check for level ID or name, so for example:

```
if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('12')) {
    ...

if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel('Gold')) {
    ...
```

You can even check for an array of levels:

```
if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(array(12,14,'Gold')))
```